# Update CSS in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following code is an example of open and close actions of a sidebar, where some CSS values should be updated to correctly show the sidebar.

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("mainContent").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("codePanel").style.marginLeft = "10px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("mainContent").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    document.getElementById("codePanel").style.marginLeft = "40px";
}
```

Now I ask myself if there is a better way to do this if I eg update more different styles?

Because in this code, I would need to add more and more similar looking lines of code which looks really clunky.

Comment: instead of manipulating `style` property, Create  CSS class and add/remove them as per requirement

Comment: But how do I add this class to all elements when they all have different ids? I'd need to update the Class for all of these elements in single lines or not?

Comment: using add and remove class  you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an initial class to all your elements that you want to update

```
<div id="sidebar" class="update"></div>
<div id="codePanel" class="update"></div>
```

Then add some styles *(be aware of [style specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))*

```
#sidebar.update {
    width : 200px;
}

#sidebar.update.updated  {
    width : 250px;
}

#codePanel.update.updated {
    color : red;
}
```

You can easily add that class to multiple elements in a loop

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.update');

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.classList.add('updated');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as the other members mentioned it is better to use `class`, what I want to add is
that you can create those css classes based on specific style for example create a class called `marginLeft50` which sets the left margin to 50 so whenever you want to update an element css you can simply do `$('sidebar').addClass('marginLeft50')`; 
keep in mind that you can add multiple classes to a single element, and since you mention `jquery` in your tags, jquery takes care of looping through all the targeted elements and updating each one of them

and as simply you can `$('selector').removeClass('className')` whenever you need to